# FindMaximum gives erroneous maxima

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I computed the NUMERIC solution to a non-linear system of ODE.
`Kfn[t] = K(t), t>=0`, is an entry in the solution. $K(t)$ is periodic with period `inertialPeriod`. I want to compute some maxima.

I coded this package:

```
$Assumptions = t >= 0
eq7 := Kf'[t] + Kf[t]^2 - L1f[t]^2 + f L1f[t] + 2 gp A1f[t] + 
   s Kf[t] == 0
eq8 := L1f'[t] + 2 Kf[t] L1f[t] - f Kf[t] + s L1f[t] == 0
eq9 := A0f'[t] + 2 Kf[t] A0f[t] == 0
eq10 := A1f'[t] + 4 Kf[t] A1f[t] == 0
sys = {eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10}
funs = {Kf[t], L1f[t], A0f[t], A1f[t]}
{gp = 1/100, omega = 2 Pi/(24 3600), fiPos = 19 Pi/90, 
 f = 2 omega Sin[fiPos], s = 10^(-6)}
inertialPeriod = 2 Pi/f
initVals = {(Pi*Sin[(19*Pi)/90])/
   1080000, -1491/1000000000 + (Pi*Sin[(19*Pi)/90])/43200, 500, 
  50*(2223081/1000000000000000000 - (13*Pi^2*Sin[(19*Pi)/90]^2)/
      24300000000)}
initCond = {Kf[0] == initVals[[1]], L1f[0] == initVals[[2]], 
  A0f[0] == initVals[[3]], A1f[0] == initVals[[4]]}
sysInit = Join[sys, initCond]
tFin = 16 inertialPeriod
solN = NDSolve[sysInit, funs, {t, 0, tFin}]
{Kfn[t_], L1fn[t_], A0fn[t_], 
  A1fn[t_]} = {Kf[t], L1f[t], A0f[t], A1f[t]} /. First[solN]
tip = inertialPeriod
t0 = 0
pltKtest = 
 Plot[{Kfn[t], 0}, {t, 0, tFin}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
  FrameLabel -> {"seconds", "K"}, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> Automatic]
iFin = 16
(*compute iFin-1 maximum points,add t=0;duplicated points can appear*)
findTmaxVdup = Module[
  {i, t, ti, maxi},
  tMaxVdup = {0}; KMaxVdup = {0};
  For[i = 1, i <= iFin - 1, i++,
    maxi = FindMaximum[{Kfn[t], t >= 0}, {t, (i - 0.1) inertialPeriod}];
    ti = t /. Last[maxi];
    tMaxVdup = Append[tMaxVdup, ti];
  ];(*end for*)
  tKMaxV = tMaxVdup;
  ntKMaxV = Dimensions[tKMaxV][[1]];
  ptsKmaxV = Table[{tKMaxV[[i]], Kfn[tKMaxV[[i]]]}, {i, 1, ntKMaxV}];
  pltKtestV = ListPlot[
    ptsKmaxV, PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
    FrameLabel -> {"seconds", "K"}, Frame -> True,
    PlotStyle -> {Green}, GridLines -> Automatic]
]

Show[pltKtest, pltKtestV]
```

In the final plot copied below, the GREEN points are `{maxi, Kfn[maxi]}` points

[image]

Green points are NOT maxima! Any hint?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the way you set your starting point for the max search. I suggest that you use constrained optimization instead, looking for maxima within ranges of e.g. ($n$ inertial periods ± 0.1).

In other words, replace the following lines of code in your `For` loop:

```
...
maxi = FindMaximum[{Kfn[t], t >= 0}, {t, (i - 0.1) inertialPeriod}]; 
ti = t /. Last[maxi]; 
tMaxVdup = Append[tMaxVdup, ti];
...
```

Your `findTamxVdup` then becomes:

```
findTmaxVdup = Module[{i, t, ti, maxi},
  tMaxVdup = {0}; KMaxVdup = {0};
  For[i = 1, i <= iFin - 1, i++,
   (* changed from here... *)
   maxi = NArgMax[{Kfn[t], i inertialPeriod - 0.1 <= t <= (i + 1) inertialPeriod - 0.1 }, t];
   tMaxVdup = Append[tMaxVdup, maxi];
   (* ... to here *)
  ];
  tKMaxV = tMaxVdup;
  ntKMaxV = Dimensions[tKMaxV][[1]];
  ptsKmaxV = Table[{tKMaxV[[i]], Kfn[tKMaxV[[i]]]}, {i, 1, ntKMaxV}];
  pltKtestV = ListPlot[ptsKmaxV, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
     FrameLabel -> {"seconds", "K"}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Green,
     GridLines -> Automatic
  ];
 ]
```

Using the rest of your definitions, then:

```
Show[pltKtest, pltKtestV]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

In fact, I would suggest furher refactoring to avoid the loop altogether and save the value at max as well as the argument at the same time, rather than recalculating the value separately. So you could replace the entire `findTmaxVdup = Module[ ... ];` with the following code:

```
ptsKmaxV = {t /. #2, #1} & @@@
  Map[
   NMaximize[{Kfn[t], # inertialPeriod - 0.1 <= t <= (# + 1) inertialPeriod - 0.1 }, t] &,
   Range[iFin - 1]
  ];

pltKtestV = 
  ListPlot[ptsKmaxV, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", FrameLabel -> {"seconds", "K"}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Green, GridLines -> Automatic];

Show[pltKtest, pltKtestV]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much MarcoB: my problem was fixed. When you are in Venice, let me know...

Comment: @FlavioSartoretto Glad it helped. Grazie per l'invito, a presto!